# How to set up a minimal Maven pom.xml file for a Heroku worker process in Java?

Tags: java, maven, heroku

First off: I'm not a Java coder. I'm new to the Java/Maven tool chain. We're using a Java library for a project which we want to launch as a Heroku background worker.

This project relies on two external libraries, the mongodb Java driver which is available through Maven's central repo, and another third party library. I've seen the [Heroku article on "unmanaged dependencies"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies), but something else appears missing, as I get an error like: `Could not find the main class: com.company.myproject.MyApp Program will exit.` when I try to run the app locally according to [Heroku's instructions on "Getting Started with Java"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java#build_and_run_your_app_locally).

I noticed that their pom.xml file contains a Maven plugin `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy dependencies, and when I check my `target/classes` folder, I don't see any of the dependencies.

Heroku also publishes a [guide on building background workers in Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku). That `pom.xml` contains a build assembly plugin, which seems more complex.

I'm a bit lost in all this ceremony (especially coming from Rails), and I'd like to stat with the simplest possible `pom.xml` to get this running. Is there a Maven archetype file for Java workers on Heroku? I'm also using NetBeans as IDE, and it would be great to use the IDE tools for this, if available, but it's a secondary priority.

Below my `pom.xml` so far:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>myproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>thirdparty</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.9</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>project-local</id>
          <name>Project-local Repo</name>
          <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: I figured out something: The `<provided>` tag is BAD. I forget where I got this from, but it screws things up. Once I took it out, Maven built and ran, even from within NetBeans.

Comment: The `<provided>` tag means that the library will be provided in some external way.

Comment: maybe [jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin/) may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy all of the dependencies into the `target/dependency` directory:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then your `Procfile` needs to include those dependencies in the classpath:

```
foo: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.myproject.Main
```

Where `com.myproject.Main` is the class name of the Java class you want to run (which must contain a `public static void main` method.  Note that this also adds the Java classes which are compiled from `src/main/java` into the `target/classes` dir.

Comment: Thanks James. That clears up a number of questions I had. It seems taht I can run the app from within NetBeans without the copy-dependencies plugin. But perhaps this won't be the case when I run it on Heroku.

Comment: You don't need to copy the dependencies when developing locally because usually the ones from the local m2 repo are used.  But that m2 repo won't exist when you run it on Heroku.

Comment: thanks for spelling this out explicitly. I suspected something like this was the case.

Comment: Also, if are a novice on the POM structure, read up on the POM Reference page http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview to learn where to put the provided Build tag into the XML structure.